# Create custom condition to populate collections in Shopify

Tags: shopify

So I have a collection that i want to auto populate with products on sale and I know that to populate it normally i just need to make a condition that says "compare at price -> is not empty" but for some of my product (probably thousands) the price and the compare price are populate with the same value.

Is there a way to create a custom condition to compare the **price** and the **compare at price**?

example: "**price** is different **compare at price**" this would populate the category if true

I just started on Shopify so please give me as much detail on the answer is possible.

Comment: Might be this [Shopify APP](https://apps.shopify.com/advanced-custom-collections?st_source=autocomplete) helps you to set up some advanced rules while creating categories, in default it is not possible

Comment: @Onkar thank you for the help with this. i was trying to avoid APP but it does look like its the only way.